# Library trying to call wire.requestFrom results in error on esp32

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am trying to run two I2C busses on a Nano32.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MS5837.h"

// Setup sensor 1
#define I2C_SDA_1_PIN 21
#define I2C_SCL_1_PIN 22
TwoWire I2C_1 = TwoWire(0);
MS5837 sensor_1;

// Setup sensor 2
#define I2C_SDA_2_PIN 17
#define I2C_SCL_2_PIN 16
TwoWire I2C_2 = TwoWire(1);
MS5837 sensor_2;

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting");
  
  I2C_1.begin(I2C_SDA_1_PIN, I2C_SCL_1_PIN);
  I2C_2.begin(I2C_SDA_2_PIN, I2C_SCL_2_PIN);

  while (!sensor_1.init(I2C_1)) {
    Serial.println("Init sensor 1 failed!");
    delay(5000);
  }

  while (!sensor_2.init(I2C_2)) {
    Serial.println("Init sensor 2 failed!");
    delay(5000);
  }
  
}

void loop() {
}
```

The MS5837 library comes from https://github.com/bluerobotics/BlueRobotics_MS5837_Library and is **not** the one that can be installed via the Arduino IDE. The reason for that is that that version does not allow the setting of the TwoWire port to use.

The issue I am facing is that I get the following error message when compiling:

```
In file included from c:\Users\tammo\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\BlueRobotics_MS5837_Library\MS5837.h:41,
                 from c:\Users\tammo\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\BlueRobotics_MS5837_Library\MS5837.cpp:1:
C:\Users\tammo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.6\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h: In member function 'bool MS5837::init(TwoWire&)':
C:\Users\tammo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.6\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:127:13: note: candidate 1: 'uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(int, int)'
     uint8_t requestFrom(int address, int size);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\tammo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.6\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:125:13: note: candidate 2: 'uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(uint8_t, uint8_t)'
     uint8_t requestFrom(uint8_t address, uint8_t size);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\tammo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.6\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h: In member function 'void MS5837::read()':
C:\Users\tammo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.6\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:127:13: note: candidate 1: 'uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(int, int)'
     uint8_t requestFrom(int address, int size);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\tammo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.6\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:125:13: note: candidate 2: 'uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(uint8_t, uint8_t)'
     uint8_t requestFrom(uint8_t address, uint8_t size);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\tammo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.6\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:127:13: note: candidate 1: 'uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(int, int)'
     uint8_t requestFrom(int address, int size);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\tammo\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.6\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:125:13: note: candidate 2: 'uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(uint8_t, uint8_t)'
     uint8_t requestFrom(uint8_t address, uint8_t size);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
Sketch uses 273661 bytes (20%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 22672 bytes (6%) of dynamic memory, leaving 305008 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
```

I am at a loss as to how to fix this and would appreciate pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the Sparkfun_Qwiic_Relay.cpp. The problem is that fromRequest has (uint8_t, uint8_t) and (int, int) declarations but it was called as fromRequest(uint8_t, int). This generated a hard compiler error. Casting the int to uint8_t fixed the compilation error. Works fine now.

wjr

Comment: Thank you. Yes. Specifically using `_i2cPort->requestFrom(MS5837_ADDR, (uint8_t) 2);` in a few places worked.